# Python Realtime Plotting from csv file

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, real-time, matplotlib-animation

This code I get from a GitHub [Link here](https://github.com/CoreyMSchafer/code_snippets/tree/master/Python/Matplotlib/09-LiveData).

I used the data_gen code to generate random numbers and continually write these numbers into the CSV file.
Then, I used the code inside snippets.txt to do real-time plotting.

I am using the Colab environment to run the two codes and both in the same directory.
The issue I am facing is that the code is not shown the plot in real-time, instead, it plots the data that is being saved in the CSV file after I interrupt the data_gen code.

Here is the two code:

Frist Code:

```
# data_gen code
    import csv
    import random
    import time
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    x_value = 0
    total_1 = 1000
    total_2 = 1000
    
    fieldnames = ["x_value", "total_1", "total_2"]
    
    with open('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/data_ranadom.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        csv_writer.writeheader()
    
    while True:
        with open('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/data_ranadom.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
            csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    
            info = {
                "x_value": x_value,
                "total_1": total_1,
                "total_2": total_2
            }
    
            csv_writer.writerow(info)
            print(x_value, total_1, total_2)
    
            x_value += 1
            total_1 = total_1 + random.randint(-6, 8)
            total_2 = total_2 + random.randint(-5, 6)
            time.sleep(1)
```

Second Code:

```
# Data_plot code
import os
import random
from itertools import count
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

plt.ion()
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

x_vals = []
y_vals = []

plt.plot([], [], label='Channel 1')
plt.plot([], [], label='Channel 2')

def animate(i):
    data = pd.read_csv('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/data_ranadom.csv')
    x = data['x_value']
    y1 = data['total_1']
    y2 = data['total_2']

    ax = plt.gca()
    line1, line2 = ax.lines

    line1.set_data(x, y1)
    line2.set_data(x, y2)

    xlim_low, xlim_high = ax.get_xlim()
    ylim_low, ylim_high = ax.get_ylim()

    ax.set_xlim(xlim_low, (x.max() + 5))

    y1max = y1.max()
    y2max = y2.max()
    current_ymax = y1max if (y1max > y2max) else y2max

    y1min = y1.min()
    y2min = y2.min()
    current_ymin = y1min if (y1min < y2min) else y2min

    ax.set_ylim((current_ymin - 5), (current_ymax + 5))


ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, interval=1000)

plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The data_gen code seems to be working as expected i.e., generating random numbers and storing them in a CVS file.

The problem I guess is in the data_plot code since it seems it's not monitoring the CSV file in real-time. Instead, it plots the saved data in the CSV file. Although, the code is working fine in the coder youtube channel ([Tutorial Link here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ercd-Ip5PfQ&t=1083s)).

Would someone help me find a way to modify the code to make it work?

I tried to use `%%writefile test2.py` for the data_plot code and then call this python script in the data_gen code using `!python '/content/gdrive/MyDrive/test2.py'` but it did not show any plot.

Comment: Have you tried to run both scripts locally?

Answer (score 0):

For the second script, you have to create a loop to plot every two or three seconds, also you have to use `plt.pause()` to give time Matplotlib to plot.

```py
import os
import random
from itertools import count
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

plt.ion()
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

x_vals = []
y_vals = []

plt.plot([], [], label='Channel 1')
plt.plot([], [], label='Channel 2')

def animate(i):
    data = pd.read_csv('data_random.csv') 
    x = data['x_value']
    y1 = data['total_1']
    y2 = data['total_2']

    ax = plt.gca()
    line1, line2 = ax.lines

    line1.set_data(x, y1)
    line2.set_data(x, y2)

    xlim_low, xlim_high = ax.get_xlim()
    ylim_low, ylim_high = ax.get_ylim()

    ax.set_xlim(xlim_low, (x.max() + 5))

    y1max = y1.max()
    y2max = y2.max()
    current_ymax = y1max if (y1max > y2max) else y2max

    y1min = y1.min()
    y2min = y2.min()
    current_ymin = y1min if (y1min < y2min) else y2min

    ax.set_ylim((current_ymin - 5), (current_ymax + 5))


while True:
    
    ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, interval=1000)
    
    plt.legend()
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.pause(3) # Number of seconds you wait to update the plot
```

By the way, it is weird that when I close the window, it cannot show the plot again. Maybe you can fix that.

Comment: Thanks for your answewr. It didn't work on colab environment. I guss the easy way is to run both scripts locally and it should work.